# java 2d game -lagging and collision issue

Tags: java

I am designing a simple java 2d game.where an aircraft shoots missiles and they hit alien ships.(pictures are attached for a better understanding).
[image]

Now I need to detect when the missile hits the alien ship. So as to count the number of total hits. I used the `rectangle1.intersects(rec2)`method, but instead of giving me an integer 1 as the answer (after the boolean of course) it gives me some funny answer. I guess like how much the two rectangles intersect...
Also when adding new aliens in an arraylist I use the following: I add new aliens every two seconds, but this slows down the game very much.

So please guide me on these two issues.

There is a `game` class (contains the main frame), `board` class (the panel on which I draw) alient, missile and `craft` class. Below I am giving the the `actionPerformed()` of the `panel` class which gets called by a timer every 2ms (the rest of the code is below).

///CODE TO BE FOCUSED ON

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class game extends JFrame {

        static long z;

    game()

    {
        add(new board());
        setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setTitle("\t\t...................::::~~~~'S GAME~~~~:::::...............");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new game();
        z = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

}

class board extends JPanel implements ActionListener

{
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    public ArrayList alien_list;
    craft craft_list = new craft();
    Label l = new Label();
    int total_hits = 0;

    public board() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addKeyListener(craft_list);
        l.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 30);
        l.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        add(l);
        t.start();

        alien_list = new ArrayList();
        alien_list.add(new alien(0, 100));
        alien_list.add(new alien(0, 150));
        alien_list.add(new alien(0, 200));

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g;

        long z = (System.currentTimeMillis() - game.z) / 1000;
        if (z >= 60)

        {
            remove(l);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g1.drawString("time up", 100, 100);
        } else

        {
            g1.drawImage(craft_list.getImage(), craft_list.getX(),
                    craft_list.getY(), null);

            ArrayList a = craft_list.getmissile();

            for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                missile m = (missile) a.get(i);
                g1.drawImage(m.getImage(), m.getX(), m.getY(), null);
            }

            l.setText("time elapsed:" + " " + +z + " " + "hits:" + " "
                    + total_hits);

            for (int i = 0; i < alien_list.size(); i++) {
                alien m = (alien) alien_list.get(i);
                g1.drawImage(m.getImage(), m.getX(), m.getY(), null);
            }

        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        ArrayList a = craft_list.getmissile();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            missile m = (missile) a.get(i);
            if (m.visible == true)
                m.move();
            else
                a.remove(i);
        }

        long z = (System.currentTimeMillis() - game.z) / 1000;
        if (z % 3 == 0)
            alien_list.add(new alien(-10, 100));

        for (int j = 0; j < alien_list.size(); j++) {
            alien m = (alien) alien_list.get(j);

            if (m.visible == true)
                m.move();
            else
                alien_list.remove(j);

        }

        craft_list.move();
        collison();
        repaint();

    }

    public void collison() {

        ArrayList a = craft_list.getmissile();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            missile m = (missile) a.get(i);
            Rectangle r1 = m.getBounds();

            for (int j = 0; j < alien_list.size(); j++) {
                alien l = (alien) alien_list.get(j);
                Rectangle r2 = l.getBounds();
                if (r1.intersects(r2)) {
                    total_hits++;

                    m.setVisible(false);
                    l.setVisible(false);

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

class craft extends KeyAdapter

{

    int x = 250;
    int y = 400;
    ArrayList m = new ArrayList();
    Image i;
    int dx, dy;

    craft() {
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("1a.jpg");
        i = i1.getImage();
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return i;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void move() {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;

        if (x < 0)
            x = 0;
        if (x > 450)
            x = 450;
        if (y > 420)
            y = 420;
        if (y < 200)
            y = 200;

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k)

    {

        int key = k.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            fire();
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = -1;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 1;
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 0;
        }
    }

    public void fire() {
        m.add(new missile(getX() + 13, getY() - 6));

    }

    public ArrayList getmissile() {
        return m;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null));
    }
}

class missile {

    Image i;

    int x, y;
    public boolean visible;

    missile(int x, int y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        visible = true;
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("1c.jpg");
        i = i1.getImage();

    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return i;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void move() {

        y--;
        if (y < 0)
            visible = false;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null));
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean t) {
        this.visible = t;
    }
}

class alien {
    Image i;
    int x, y;;
    public boolean visible;

    public alien(int x, int y)

    {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("b.jpg");
        i = i1.getImage();
        visible = true;

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;

    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;

    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return i;
    }

    public void move() {

        x++;
        if (x > 500)
            visible = false;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null));
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean t) {
        this.visible = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question sorry. Your problem is with `rectangle1.intersects(rec2)` but the issue is that you're counting the intersection more than once?

Comment: when the two rectangles collide i.e. the missile pic and the alien pic ,then 'n' should be incremented by '1'...but it gets incremented to 50,60,70,and so on..

Comment: Your increment is in a `for` loop.  Have you tested your loop to see if it's iterating over what you think it should?  Also, for performance, are you double-buffering as you draw?

Comment: umm..rechecked it with continue and break statements.still the same issue.it is incrementing the total are that is intersected i guess..
and yes double-buffering is set to true.the issue lies in addition of new alien ships.can u please provide me some insight on how to add alien ships randomly without slowing the game

Answer (score 2):

Ok, your code format is kind of unreadable and invites everybody to oversee otherwise obvious bugs. That is what I have seen so far for your performance issue:

1. getBounds() creates a new Rectangle instance every time it gets called. You should update the bounds rectangle at the last line of your move() and just return the rectangle instance instead of creating a new one.
2. Reuse Image or ImageIcon objects. There is no need to load the same jpg file over and over again in a constructor. Make it static or use a image cache.
3. Instead of o++ in fire() you should use o = m.size(). Mainly because you never call o--, you only remove the rocket from the ArrayList.

And at that point everybody loses track of what `o` and `m` means. Name your variables better! o should be amountOfRockets and m should be listOfRockets.

When you use Eclipse, press ctrl + shift + f to format the code which I highly recommend. After that go through your code and name the variables correctly. That means you should give them a descriptive name. And finally: let the name of your classes start with an upper case.

Very likely that this will not yet remove all issues but it will at least help us to understand and read your code easier... which might lead us to a solution...

Update:

You still haven't done 1. and 2. I suggested but you did 3.

Here is what 1. should be as a sample for the Alien class:

```
private Rectangle bounds

//constructor
Alien() {
    // your stuff and the bounds:
    bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, i.getWidth(null), i.getHeight(null));
}

public void move() {
    bounds.x++;
    if (bounds.x > 500)
        visible = false;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return bounds;
}
```

You need to implement that for the Rocket class as well.

What I still don't get is where you remove the old Alien objects. Just setting their visibility is not enough. You should remove them from the list of your Alien objects. Otherwise you will loop through objects that are not there anymore.

Comment: 2.) makes it miss the cache lanes when cycling through those spaceships and missiles which have images in them(he is accessing only single x and y values between big pictures ), but this is only a minor performance loss right? Creating rectangles in a O(n*m) can be worse or JIT optimizes it away?

Comment: Creating an object is always expensive. Consider the massive amount of collision checks that can be performed in one single step, it should be optimized.

Comment: thank god somebody answered.Ohkay , will keep that eclipse formatting thing in mind from now on.

Comment: Feel free to update the code in the question as well and report back if you had performance improvements. If not I will take a look again (but only on the formatted code! :D)

Comment: I need to check the rectangle of every missile with every alien, don't I ?
.So will i not need to check it with each and everyone?

Comment: you basically only need to iterate over the alien ships and compare each ship with each rocket but not the rockets with rockets

Comment: Please wait mate..(and pardon me for being greedy :D ) .I need it to work badly..letme format it and work on 1-2 issues you stated.

Comment: Damn.our comments are out of synch.

Comment: r1 is the rectangle for one missile.And r2 is the rectangle for each alien ship.I am using the for loops to checck them like a 2D array.?There can't be another way,can it?

Comment: In `actionPerformed()` only i check , which all items have their visibility as false , i remove those items

Comment: ok and the main problem is currently what? Performance or collision?

Comment: and how will shifting the creation of `rectangle object` to the `constructor` help? won't a new rectangle object be created everytime a new `missile object` is created ?

Comment: main issue  is collison..how to get the total_hit updated only once per rectangle intersection

Comment: for performance i find that it is directly related to the number of existing missiles and alien ships..as soon as the missiles are removed from the `ArrayList` , it speeds up..so after i have my dinner i will change it to `LinkedList` and see

Comment: hey great new buddy..finally got it working..i used a new algorithm which induces a new alien ship only when one of the previous one is destroyed ..this solved it .but  can you please telme now why it was not working with a large no of alien ships?